# p-dataView Getting values of selected rows

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

Using primeNG p-dataview, I have a checkbox and a dropdown for every row. My goal is If I check the checkobox I want to get the value of the dropdon for the selected row (if selectd) same the other way around, If a user select a value from the dropdown I want to see if  the checkbox was already checked for this raw. How can I accomplish this ?

**HTML**

```
<p-dataView [value]="iErsaDefaultApps" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20" [sortField]="sortField" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" paginatorPosition="both">
    <ng-template let-apps let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="listItem">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleSelectedApp($event)" id="defaultAppID" name="defaultApps" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px" [value]='apps.app_id'> {{apps.app_name}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="role" class="dropdown" style="width:60%" (ngModelChange)="selectedDefaultAppRole($event,rowIndex)" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole[rowIndex]" >
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="" selected>Select</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor='let role of apps.roles' [ngValue]="role.app_role_id">
                {{role.app_role_name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

**TS**

```
    selectedRole: any[] = []

    toggleSelectedApp(event: any)
    {
       //need to check the values of the drpown?
       console.log('checkbox' + event.srcElement.checked);
    }
}

selectedDefaultAppRole(event: any, index:any) {
    //also need to check th value of the checkbox
    console.log('selected defult dropdown ' + event);
    console.log('selected index ' + event);
  }
```

***********************************************************Update**********************************************
1) selectedDefaultAppRole will not know i the checkbox is checked or not
2) toggleSelectedApp will not know what drpdown value is selected
**HTML**

```
<p-dataView [value]="iErsaDefaultApps" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20">
    <ng-template let-apps let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="listItem">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleSelectedApp($event, rowIndexValue)" id="defaultAppID" name="defaultApps"
                style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px" [value]='apps.app_id'> {{apps.app_name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="role" class="dropdown" style="width:60%" (ngModelChange)="selectedDefaultAppRole($event, rowIndexValue,apps.app_id)"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedRole[rowIndexValue]" >
                <option class="dropdown-item" value="" selected>Select</option>
                <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor='let role of apps.roles' [ngValue]="role.app_role_id">
                    {{role.app_role_name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

**TS**
2 issues with

```
   toggleSelectedApp(event: any, rowIndexValue: any)
    {

                this.selectedObject = this.iErsaAppList
               .find(x => x.app_id == event.srcElement.value);

           const index: number = this.iErsaDefaultApps.indexOf(this.selectedObject);

                    const cApp = this.iErsaDefaultApps.filter(a => a.app_id === index);
               console.log('currentApp', cApp);

    }

   selectedDefaultAppRole(event: any, index: number,app_id:number) {
        console.log('selected app_id ' + app_id);

        const cApp = this.iErsaDefaultApps.filter(a => a.app_id == app_id);
            console.log('currentAppRole', cApp);
            console.log('currentAppRole', event);

    }
```

**interface**

```
export interface IErsaApps {

        app_id: number;
        app_type_id: number;
        app_name: string;
        app_roles: string;
        app_sort_id?: number;
       roles: Array<IErsaAppRoles>
}

export interface IErsaAppRoles {

    app_role_id: number;
    app_role_app_id: number;
    app_role_name: string;
    app_role_sort_id?: number;

}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using the primeng [table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) to take advantage of the [selection](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/selection) functionality it offers, rather than using the dataview.

Comment: we already have the grid view and really wanted it to use the layout feature

Comment: I get you. If you console log the entire `event` in the functions that you have now, like `toggleSelectedApp` and `selectedDefaultAppRole`, does that contain any of the values you would like to access? Also, you have some "lets" you are using as a part of your template, are those something you can pass into the functions so you can access a value?

Comment: toggleSelectedApp will give me the the vaue f the checkbox and if the checbox is checked...but not sure how do i get the selected dropdown value................function selectedDefaultAppRole is called when i select a value from the dropdown but it only index no value

Comment: lets not sure what do you want to pass into a function...

Comment: any new ideas on how to move forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about making these updates to your template:

```
<p-dataView [value]="iErsaDefaultApps" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20">
  <ng-template let-apps let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="listItem">
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleSelectedApp($event, rowIndexValue)" id="defaultAppID" name="defaultApps"
        style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px"
            [value]='apps.app_id'> {{apps.app_name}}
  </div>
  <div>
      <select name="role" class="dropdown" style="width:60%"
        (change)="selectedDefaultAppRole($event, rowIndexValue)" [(ngModel)]="apps.app_role">
          <option class="dropdown-item" value="" selected>Select</option>
          <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor='let role of apps.roles' [value]="role.app_role_id">
              {{role.app_role_name}}
          </option>
      </select>
  </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

This is similar to what you have now, with the addition of passing the `rowIndexValue` value into the `toggleSelectedApp` and `selectedDefaultAppRole` functions. The `rowIndexValue` is made available in the template because you used `let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex"`. This means the index from the data coming from `iErsaDefaultApps` will be available for use.

**UPDATE:** I changed what you were binding to with `ngModel` to set the chosen value on the `apps.app_role` directly. Change `[value]="role.app_role_id"` to `[value]="role.app_role_name"` if you would rather have the role name stored.

Then you can access the information in the TS code like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  iErsaDefaultApps = [{
    app_id: 1,
    app_name: 'App One',
    app_role: '',
    roles: [{
      app_role_id: 0,
      app_role_name: 'App Role One'
    },
    {
      app_role_id: 1,
      app_role_name: 'App Role Two'
    }]
  },
  {
    app_id: 3,
    app_name: 'App Two',
    app_role: '',
    roles: [{
      app_role_id: 0,
      app_role_name: 'App Role One'
    },
    {
      app_role_id: 1,
      app_role_name: 'App Role Two'
    }]
  }];

  selectedApps: Set<IErsaApps> = new Set<IErsaApps>();

  toggleSelectedApp(event: any, rowIndexValue: number) {
    // This adds or remove items from the selectedApps set
    const cApp = this.iErsaDefaultApps[rowIndexValue];
    console.log('Selected App', cApp);
    if (event.srcElement.checked) {
      this.selectedApps.add(cApp);
    } else {
      this.selectedApps.delete(cApp);
    }
    console.log('Selected Apps', this.selectedApps);
  }

  selectedDefaultAppRole(event: any, index: any) {
    // Now you can find out of the current app is selected
    const cApp = this.iErsaDefaultApps[index];
    console.log('Selected App', cApp);
    const isAppSelected = this.selectedApps.has(cApp);
    console.log('Is App Selected', isAppSelected);
    console.log('Selected Apps', this.selectedApps);
  }
}


export interface IErsaApps {
  app_id: number;
  app_name: string;
  app_role: string;
  roles: Array<IErsaAppRoles>;
}

export interface IErsaAppRoles {
  app_role_id: number;
  app_role_name: string;
}
```

This adds a simple lookup based on the index passed in from the template. Then, it tries to see if the `selectedApps` set `has` the app in it.

Do whatever else you need to when a function is called.

Comment: updated my above code, index does not work because it does not match my array. I made some change to get the right row, however, i still have two issues..see above code..I think I need to ad two more value to my interface (checked value for the checkbox and selected vlaue or the dropdown ) but was wondering if there is a better way

Comment: Rather than doing a filter, just doing `this.iErsaDefaultApps[rowIndexValue]`, or `this.iErsaDefaultApps[index]`, might do the trick. I don't know how that would work with sorting, though.

Comment: yes, this.iErsaDefaultApps[index] it does work and make the code simple , however, i am still having the same issue this.iErsaDefaultApps[index]  will give me the entire selected object but it will not tell me if the checkbox is checked and what dropdown values was selected. since each control has its own even click

Comment: so toggleSelectedApp method will not et me which values dropdown values was selected for this row , and selectedDefaultAppRole will not give me f the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: I see. Makes sense. I will have another look. I probably won't have any more information until morning.

Comment: Updates posted. Take a look when you have time.

Comment: got it, basically i just need to have the selected values as part of my object, which I will do...I was originally wondering f there is another way to selected the controls of the selected roles and access them via different functions...will mark it as an answer...thaks for you help